# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate nested schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update(push) an array inside a nested schema that is inside another nested schema.

----This is my Schema----

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const subtaskSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    isCompleted: Boolean,
})

const taskSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    status: String,
    subtasks: [subtaskSchema]
})

const columnSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    tasks: [taskSchema]
})

const boardSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    columns: [columnSchema]
})

const mainSchema = new Schema({
  boards: [boardSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('boards', mainSchema)
```

----This is my route ----

`router.patch('/tasks/:id', createTasks)`

----This is my Board controller----

```
const createTasks = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No valid id' })
    }

    // add to the database
    try {
        **const boards = await board.findOneAndUpdate({ "boards.columns._id": id }, {
            ...req.body
        })**
        res.status(200).json(boards)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }
}
```

----This is my Board json data----

```
    {
        "_id": "64562878b881a9551f5e5b1c",
        "boards": [
          {
            "name": "newboard",
            "_id": "6459d699de8a2cceb28ed604",
            "columns": [
              {
                "name": "newColumn",
                "_id": "6459d6b6de8a2cceb28ed60d",
                **"tasks": [
                  
                ]**
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
        "name": "trust"
      }
```

----I'm trying to push data into boards.columns.tasks array by putting this into req.body----

`{"$push": {"boards.columns.$.tasks": {"title": "newTitle"}}}`

----The req.params.id I used was 6459d6b6de8a2cceb28ed60d which is the boards.columns._id----

```
const { id } = req.params
const boards = await board.findOneAndUpdate({ "boards.columns._id": id }, {
            ...req.body
        })
```

---- so the url I used was ----

http://localhost:4000/api/boards/tasks/6459d6b6de8a2cceb28ed60d

You might ask how I insert data into the boards array in the first place so here is what i did for that.

```
const boards = await board.findOneAndUpdate({ "boards._id": id }, {
        ...req.body
    })
```

---- req.param.id used is boards.id : 6459d699de8a2cceb28ed604

`http://localhost:4000/api/boards/column/6459d699de8a2cceb28ed604`
`{"$push":{"boards.$.columns": {"name": "newColumn"}}}`

So this worked for me for pushing data into "columns" array (and I got {"name": "newColumn"} look above json data) so I thought push data into "tasks" array should be easy but no it wasn't. I'm hard stuck here any help would be grateful.

----------------------------SOLUTION Below-----------------------------------
----------------------------SOLUTION Below-----------------------------------
----------------------------SOLUTION Below-----------------------------------
----------------------------SOLUTION Below-----------------------------------

Edited: so this took me a long time to figure it out. I tried everything and nothing worked so of course I used chatgpt as a last resort and it fixed it in 1 second. Note to myself, use chatgpt first. So, here is the solution to this problem to anyone who's suffering from this.

-------------Solution------------

`router.patch('/tasks/:id/:id2', createTasks)`

```
const { id, id2 } = req.params

const boards = await board.updateOne({ "boards._id": id, "boards.columns._id": id2 }, {
            ...req.body
        })
```

------This is req.body-----

`{ "$push": { "boards.$[].columns.$[].tasks": { "title": "newTask" } } }`

Comment: Have you tried arrayFilters?

Comment: @Joe I have not. I should try that just dont know how yet. I should look it up thanks